# Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по java income calculator

Tags: java, java-ee, while, java-8, java-stream

есть задание:

1. Рассчитайте минимальную сумму дохода, при вводе которой программа ответит, что инвестировать можно. Для этого необязательно ждать ввод суммы от пользователя. Примените существующие выражения в программе и выведите обратную формулу, удовлетворяющую условию инвестирования.
2. Выведите значение в консоль в начале метода main():
   //расчёт и вывод минимальной суммы дохода для инвестирования
3. Протестируйте получившиеся значения — введите их в программу. Если всё верно, вы получите ответ: Компания может инвестировать: да
4. Введите значение меньше полученного на 1. Если всё верно, вы получите ответ:
   Компания может инвестировать: нет
5. Напишите сумму, которая у вас получилась.

Не понимаю как решить... Помогите пожалуйста!

```
import java.util.Scanner; //инициализация сканера для считывания
    
    public class Main //класс Main
    {
        private static int minIncome = 200000; // минимальная сумма дохода
        private static int maxIncome = 900000; //максимальная сумма дохода
    
        private static int officeRentCharge = 140000; //Аренда офиса
        private static int telephonyCharge = 12000; //Оплата телефона
        private static int internetAccessCharge = 7200; //оплата интернета
    
        private static int assistantSalary = 45000; //Зарплата асистента
        private static int financeManagerSalary = 90000; //Зарплата бугалтера
    
        private static double mainTaxPercent = 0.24; //Процент налога
        private static double managerPercent = 0.15; //Процент менеджера
    
        private static double minInvestmentsAmount = 100000; //Минимальный порог инвестирования
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            while(true) //цикл
            {
                System.out.println("Введите сумму доходов компании за месяц " + "(от 200 до 900 тысяч рублей): "); //вывод запроса на ввод
                int income = (new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt(); //Получаем значение с командной строки
    
                if(!checkIncomeRange(income)) { //условие выполняется если сумма доходов компании за месяц в пределах заданного диапазона
                    continue;
                }
    
                double managerSalary = income * managerPercent; //зарплата менеджера сумма доходов*Процент менеджера
                double pureIncome = income - managerSalary - calculateFixedCharges(); //чистый доход = сумма доходов - зарплата менеджера - постоянные доходы
                double taxAmount = mainTaxPercent * pureIncome; // расчёт суммы налога = Процент налога * чистый доход
                double pureIncomeAfterTax = pureIncome - taxAmount; //прибыль = чистый доход - сумму налога
    
                boolean canMakeInvestments = pureIncomeAfterTax >= minInvestmentsAmount; // присвоение true если прибыль больше либо равна минимальному порогу инвестирования
    
                System.out.println("Зарплата менеджера: " + managerSalary); //отображение зарплаты менеджера
                System.out.println("Общая сумма налогов: " + (taxAmount > 0 ? taxAmount : 0)); //вывод суммы налогов если есть чистый доход
                System.out.println("Компания может инвестировать: " + (canMakeInvestments ? "да" : "нет")); //выводит может ли команда инвестировать на основании строки 37
                if(pureIncome < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Бюджет в минусе! Нужно срочно зарабатывать!"); //выводится если чистая прибль меньше 0
                }
            }
        }
    
        private static boolean checkIncomeRange(int income) //проверка суммы доходов компании за месяц
        {
            if(income < minIncome) //проверка нижнего значения
            {
                System.out.println("Доход меньше нижней границы");
                return false;
            }
            if(income > maxIncome) //проверка верхнего значения
            {
                System.out.println("Доход выше верхней границы");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        private static int calculateFixedCharges() //подсчёт постоянных расходов
        {
            return officeRentCharge +
                    telephonyCharge +
                    internetAccessCharge +
                    assistantSalary +
                    financeManagerSalary;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос то в чём?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    minIncome =   (int)((minInvestmentsAmount + calculateFixedCharges() * (1 - mainTaxPercent))/ ((1 - mainTaxPercent) * (1 - managerPercent)) + 1);
    System.out.println("Минимальный доход для инвестиций: " + minIncome);
```

Тут мы ищем минимальную сумму при которой можно инвестировать.
А это значит, что мы берем минимальную сумму для инвестирования и постоянные издержки, суммируем их. Далее идет математические действия с этой суммой (деление дробей).
Основная зависимость это минимальная сумма инвестиций и постоянные расходы. изменяя их вы будете получать разные минимальные значения суммы с которой можно инвестировать с учетом всех расходов.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём заключается магия, и почему не трогать?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!